# htaccess subdomain redirect to folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to get my subdomain to show the article path as well but it won't work.
if I go to blog.domain.com, it redirects to `https://www.domain.com/blog/`

I want `https://www.domain.com/blog/` to stay **blog.domain.com**
and if I go to `https://www.domain.com/blog/article/1` to show **blog.domain.com/article/1/**

With godaddy's cpanel, I added the subdomain forwarding (without masking - as it was always showing blog.domain.com and I want to see the path so I removed the masking)

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This did not seem to do anything..

**EDIT**

I placed the htaccess only in the root folder.
And I also tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^blog(.*)$ http://blog.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

when i go to blog.domain.com it redirects to www.domain.com/blog/ and the page does not load

Comment: Does both "www.domain.com" and "blog.domain.com" point to the same document root? (meaning going to `http://blog.domain.com/blog/` is the same as `http://www.domain.com/blog/`)

Comment: No, www.domain.com/blog/ is blog.domain.com

Comment: Does it matter if I have subdomain forwarding (301) on godaddy? I have it set to: when going to blog.domain.com -> redirect to www.domain.com/blog

Comment: So is the document root for `http://blog.domain.com/`, in the `/blog/` directory?

Comment: yes.. domain.com/blog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have it set to: when going to blog.domain.com -> redirect to www.domain.com/blog

This is why your browser's location bar is changing. When you redirect, the server is responding to the browser by saying "What you're looking for is not at the URL you just went to, it is at (in the case of 301, permanently) this NEW URL", so the browser loads the new URL, sending an entirely new and separate request to the new URL. That causes the location bar to change.

Turn off that redirect.

Then you should be able to leave the rule that you have in the root folder *for your main domain*:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

You don't need to mess with that other rule since your *document root for the `blog.domain.com` is already `/blog/`.

Comment: so you're saying i should remove the subdomain forwarding on godaddy? once i do that and add the htaccess code, will people be able to go on blog.domain.com and see my blog?

Comment: @user235196 assuming that you've made `/blog` the document root for the `blog.domain.com` domain which has zero to do with redirects. And by "redirect" I mean the definition that I've given above.

Comment: Ok so, I have a folder called blog in the root which has pages in it. I used to go to www.domain.com/blog/index.php. when I go to blog.domain.com/article/3, it redirects to http://www.domain.com/blog/article/3

Comment: @user235196 if you don't want that redirect, then remove it

Comment: I tried creating a test folder (domain.com/test/) and added the htaccess code in and then went to test.domain.com and the page didn't load

Comment: @user235196 [You have to set your subdomain up](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&safe=off&q=godaddy+cpanel+subdomain), "test.domain.com" won't magically have a new document root. What you **don't want to do** is *redirect* the subdomain to that folder.

Comment: i get a redirect loop after i removed it from godaddy